# Rails. Trying to send a parameter from a Form (using first form_tag, then traditional html)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have read the two different types of helpers,

```
form_for and form_tag
```

This is not bound to the model, I just want to pass some search parameters to one method in the controller.

I tried using this helper, but it would not display the text field.

```
<% form_tag({controller: "articles", action: "search"}, method: "get") do %>
     <p>
       Subject:<br />
       <%= text_field_tag "q" %>
     </p>
<% end % >
```

So, then I switched to the one that everybody understands:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/articles/search" method="get" class="nifty_form">'
                     <p>
                       Subject:<br />
                       <input type ="text" name ="q">
                     </p>
<input type="submit" value="send">
```

In the controller, I just wanted to check if it had gotten the parameter, so I wanted it displayed:

```
def search
   render plain: params[:q].inspect
  end
```

But I got this error:

```
NoMethodError in ArticlesController#show
undefined method `set_article' for #<ArticlesController:0x007faa95e9ad08>
```

I don't understand. Why is it complaining about the method show?

In the first place, it does exist, although only as

```
def show
end
```

and in the second place, I am trying to send that parameter to the search method which should print it out.

ADDED CODE

As requested. I am including more of the Controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def search
   render plain: params[:q].inspect
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show

  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    render "digitmedia/home"
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
```

Comment: Please post your full controller code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified a `set_article` before action which will be executed before the specified action of that controller. However that function is not defined - which causes the error.

Comment: Rails is expecting a function named `set_article` in the controller. Is that defined ?

Comment: For more information about using before/after filters Rails guide has a dedicated section : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I certainly did not downvote your question, though lack of research is evident from the question description.  I would request you to remove the inflammatory comment else it is likely that you will be flagged by SO members.